# Saving a video to my camera roll returns error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I'm attempting to use ReplayKit and save the video of the screen capture to my camera roll.

However I'm getting an error when I try to save it at the very bottom of my code, that last error check: "Video did not save for some reason"

> Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 “(null)“)
>
> “The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)”

I've looked around at a number of other questions similar to this but most of them have a trail of unanswered comments similar to "I'm getting this too, did you ever get an answer to this"

Would love some help on this. Thanks!

````
    private func startRecording() {
        //Create the file path to write to
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
        self.videoOutputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(UUID.init().description + ".mp4"))
​
        //Check the file does not already exist by deleting it if it does
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: videoOutputURL!)
        } catch {}
​
        do {
            try videoWriter = AVAssetWriter(outputURL: videoOutputURL!, fileType: .mp4)
        } catch let writerError as NSError {
            print("Error opening video file", writerError);
            videoWriter = nil;
            return;
        }
​
        //Create the video settings
        let videoSettings: [String : Any] = [
            AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
            AVVideoWidthKey: view.bounds.width,
            AVVideoHeightKey: view.bounds.height
        ]
​
        //Create the asset writer input object whihc is actually used to write out the video
        //with the video settings we have created
        videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoSettings);
        videoWriterInput!.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        videoWriter?.add(videoWriterInput!);
​
        let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
        guard recorder.isAvailable else { return } // or throw error
​
        recorder.startCapture(handler: { (buffer, sampleType, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                return DispatchQueue.main.async { self.presentError(error!) }
            }
​
            switch sampleType {
            case .video:
                print("writing sample....")
​
                switch self.videoWriter!.status {
                case .unknown:
                    if self.videoWriter?.startWriting != nil {
                        print("Starting writing")
​
                        self.videoWriter!.startWriting()
                        self.videoWriter!.startSession(atSourceTime:  CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(buffer))
                    }
​
                case .writing:
                    if self.videoWriterInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                        print("Writing a sample")
​
                        if  self.videoWriterInput!.append(buffer) == false {
                            print(" we have a problem writing video")
                        }
                    }
                default: break
                }
​
            default:
                print("not a video sample, so ignore");
            }
        })
    }
​
    private func stopRecording() {
        let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()

        recorder.stopCapture { [unowned self] error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return DispatchQueue.main.async { self.presentError(error!) }
            }

            self.saveVideoToCameraRoll(completion: completion)
        }

    }

    func saveVideoToCameraRoll(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        //Now save the video
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            print(self.videoOutputURL!)
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: self.videoOutputURL!)
        }) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in
                    completion?()
                }
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            if error != nil {
                print("Video did not save for some reason", error.debugDescription)
                debugPrint(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error is nil")
            }
        }
    }

    ```
````

Comment: can you clarify where this error is occurring, you have several error prints

Comment: Sure, it's the very bottom, "video did not save for some reason" will add to my original post too

Comment: recorder.stopCapture actually seems to have some sort of async callback, its fair to assume that it doesn't happen instantly. you may be trying to access the `atFileURL` too early, maybe try separate the save out to a separate function thats called in the callback of the stopRecording? (you might be able to check if theres anything at the URL also just before you try creating the asset)

Comment: @gadu good catch. I moved the save functionality to a different function which is called inside of the `stopCapture` callback but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to finish writing to the file when you stop recording:

```swift
private func stopRecording() {
    let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
    recorder.stopCapture { [unowned self] error in
        ...
        self.videoWriter?.finishWriting {
            self.saveVideoToCameraRoll(completion: completion)
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel. Thats what I was missing